# How can I get the default theme dictionaries

Tags: wpf, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml

Metro applications use a set a default theme resource dictionaries.

Is there a way to see these dictionaries?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You get the default resources in generic.xaml and themeresources.xaml that you can find in:

c:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\winrt\xaml\design

Then also when you create a new project - you get StandardStyles.xaml in YourApplication\Common.

Also [WinRT XAML Toolkit](http://bit.ly/WinRTXamlToolkit) includes a Styles Browser application that allows to browse a lot of the standard styles visualized in a running application.